# show more than 8 items in the Data Validation drop down list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, data-validation, winapi

I have added a simple data validation to a cell but it only displays 8 items in the dropdown.

[image]

[Excluding the combobox solution](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/02/03/3-types-of-excel-drop-down-lists-compared/) and probably involving some WinAPI is there a way to make the drop down list longer/*bigger*?

Answer (score 2):

@ me how: No, you cannot enlarge the displayed portion of the dropdown list - but the list itself can cover way more than 8 entries (over 32 000 entries actually). This is the reasen, why the dropdown list shows a scroll bar, if the covered entries exceed the displayed space.

Maybe this is also of interest to you: if you select the cell containing a dropdown list you can enter the dropdown using ALT + Arrowdown. This way no mouse is needed to perform data input using the dropdown list.

Cheers!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and often the question is misunderstood with commenters saying "More than 8 lines are possible - just use the slider!.” The real question is: “How can I display more than 8 lines and not have to use the slider?”

The short answer is: “No, the drop-down is stuck at 8 lines.”

The longer answer is that it is possible by using the developer tab (customize your ribbon if you can’t see it), then “insert” and selected the “combo box form control.” A few clicks later and you'll have an unattractive drop down box that cannot be copied.

If you want a range, you’ll need to make separate combo boxes. The limitation is that so far I haven't been able to make other cells link or refer to the info in that combo box.